# apt-get unable to fetch archives

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I'm trying to install a package using `apt-get` as root on a Linux Mint host:

```
# apt-get install gparted
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a
Suggested packages:
  xfsprogs reiserfsprogs reiser4progs jfsutils kpartx dmraid gpart
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  gparted libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 343 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,557 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,870 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
WARNING: The following packages cannot be authenticated!
  libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a gparted
Install these packages without verification [y/N]? Y
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a i386 1:2.24.2-1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ oneiric/main gparted i386 0.8.1-1ubuntu4
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gtkmm2.4/libgtkmm-2.4-1c2a_2.24.2-1_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gparted/gparted_0.8.1-1ubuntu4_i386.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.201 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

As you can see, `apt-get` is unable to fetch files. I've checked my network connection: I'm able to `ping` the host where apt-get fails to fetch the files:

```
# ping 91.189.92.201
PING 91.189.92.201 (91.189.92.201) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 91.189.92.201: icmp_req=1 ttl=128 time=51.4 ms
```

Tried as well with `apt-get update` and `--fix-missing` but none worked. Any idea how to solve the issue ?

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: As twan163 answered, you are using an obsolete release, but since mint behaves like Ubuntu, you may be able to issue a `do-release-upgrade -d` to go from 12 to 17.1

Answer (score 1):

Oneiric (for Linux Mint) is obsolete.

http://www.linuxmint.com/oldreleases.php